# json parsing scala java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, noclassdeffounderror

I have a json object which i want to parse into the form of a Map in scala
the json object in stored in a text file i read the object from that and then 
input it in the parse function of library `net.liftweb.json._` as string

however whenever i try to do the above i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:scala.Predef$.intWrapper(I)Lscala/runtime/RichInt;
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$Buffer.near(JsonParser.scala:379)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$Parser.fail(JsonParser.scala:228)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$Parser.nextToken(JsonParser.scala:313)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$$anonfun$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:184)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$$anonfun$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:141)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$.parse(JsonParser.scala:80)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$.parse(JsonParser.scala:45)
at net.liftweb.json.package$.parse(package.scala:41)
at Json_parser$$anonfun$filereader$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Json_parser.scala:200)
at Json_parser$$anonfun$filereader$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Json_parser.scala:183)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at Json_parser$$anonfun$filereader$2.apply(Json_parser.scala:183)
at Json_parser$$anonfun$filereader$2.apply(Json_parser.scala:167)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at Json_parser$.filereader(Json_parser.scala:167)
at Json_parser$.main(Json_parser.scala:242)
at Json_parser.main(Json_parser.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Here is my relavant code

```
import java.io.File
import net.liftweb.json._
var f = scala.io.Source.fromFile(pathfinal)
var report_json = f.mkString
f.close()
var obj=report_json.toString
println(obj)
var map_json=parse(obj).asInstanceOf[JObject].values
println(map_json)
```

the information in the text file is in this json format

```
{"something":"anything","something1":{"....":"..."},"something3":"[..,..,..]"}
```

What could be the possible reasons for this error and how to rectify it
I searched the error and found in some post people said that the version mismatch of 
imported library however I downloaded the library  net.liftweb:lift-json_2.9.1-1:2.5-M1
again and deleted the old one but the error still prevails

Comment: (edited as om-nom-nom is correct) Are you using scala 2.9.1? This happens quite often as each major release is incompatible

Comment: @Augusto not each, only major ones are binary imcompatible -- 2.8.1 vs 2.9.x vs 2.10.x vs 2.11.x

Comment: I am using scala version 2.10 , I tried to install 2.9 version but it says u cannot install the older version without removing the newer one